# What is the reason for the double negation -(-n)?

Tags: c

I'm going through some legacy code and I've seen something like

```
char n = 65;
char str[1024];
sprintf(str, "%d", -(-n));
```

Why has the author (no longer present) written `-(-n)` rather than just `n`? Wouldn't `--n` suffice?

Comment: --n would be pre decrement intead of double negation.

Comment: It's a way of converting `n` to a value of type `int`, without doing an explicit type conversion.

Comment: @Peter: That is useless, as `char` is converted to `int` anyway for the argument. The double negation can invoke UB for some (although uncommon) targets.

Comment: @Olaf: but not with the value of 65; you are correct in general though. I was thinking about mentioning something about assigning to 65 rather than perhaps 'A' which would be more portable if that was the intention.

Comment: @Bathsheba: The code would not make much sense as prodiction code, so I suspect OP means the `65` (which incidenitally happens to be the ASCII-code of `'A'`) just as an example.

Comment: @Olaf - what you say is true.  But my comment was about what the construct `-(-n)` is doing, not whether it is useful to do it.  And, for a `char` with value `65`, no undefined behaviour is introduced.

Comment: @Peter: "It's a way of converting n to a value of type `int`" - And that is useless.

Comment: @Olaf - plenty of programmers do useless things.   The OP was seeking to understand what the construct is, presumably because of encountering code which uses it.   Without understanding what a construct does, it is not possible to reason about whether it is needed or useless.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The first thing to note is that `--n` actually **decreases** `n` by 1 and evaluates to the new value, with the *type* `char`; so it does something very different to `-(-n)`. **Don't** change the code to that!

`-n` performs a unary negation of `n` and is also an expresion of type `int` due to the *type promotion* rules of C. The further negation sets it back to the original value but with the *type* `int` retained.

So `-(-n)` is actually a verbose way of writing `+n`, which is often though to be a no-op but in this case it converts the *type* of `n` to an `int`.

I suspect the author is guarding themselves against errant refactoring and they were worried about mismatching the type of the argument with the format specifier `%d`.

But in this *particular* case it does not matter: `sprintf` will automatically promote the `char` type to an `int`, so it's perfectly safe to write

`sprintf(str, "%d", n);`

Do also consider reducing the size of the `str` buffer if that's "real" code, and consider using the safer `snprintf` variant.

(As a final remark note that a double negation can yield signed integral type overflow, so do use with caution.)

Comment: A problem arises with `int` and `char` having the same bitwidth. For e.g. 2's complement `INT_MIN` will invoke UB when negated. Similar if `char` is unsigned, for all values > `INT_MAX`. I don't see any benefit in this construct.