# Why is char a = 65 less portable than char a = 'A'

Tags: c

I've just asked this question [What is the reason for the double negation -(-n)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39331791/what-is-the-reason-for-the-double-negation-n/39331818#39331818) where the answerer mentions in a comment that

`char a = 'A';`

is more portable than

`char a = 65;`

Why is this? Surely they are exactly the same?

Comment: Because not all systems uses ASCII. There are still systems running that uses e.g. [EBCDIC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EBCDIC), where `A` is not equal to `65`.

Comment: I don't understand the downvoting. Could you please explain why this is a bad question? I don't understand.

Comment: How about a simple search about "character encoding C"?

Comment: But how do I know I need to search for that? I don't think that term appears anywhere in K&R.

Comment: Nowadays almost every system uses ASCII. But anyway it's still very bad practice because if you write `char a = 65;` the reader must know that 65 is 'A' but if you write `char a = 'A';` everything is clear.

Comment: I agree with OP that this doesn't deserve downvotes. There's too much downvoting of beginner-level questions on SO. Just because something's obvious to you doesn't mean it's obvious to everyone.

Comment: It depends what you do with it. For example, if you are running in a non-ASCII environment, but need to send an ASCII letter 'A' somewhere, you'd need to use the numeric constant.

Comment: Portability considerations aside, if you need the A character, write `'A'`. Does the job perfectly well. Why should anyone want to write 65 or anything else instead?

Comment: @IanAbbott: Not sure if that works with `#pragma`, but e.g. gcc allows to specify a host/target encoding by options.

Comment: @MichaelWalz: Actually almost **no** system today uses `ASCII`. Most use one of the Unicode variants or some of the 8-bit codes like the ISO8859 zoo.

Comment: @chiastic-security: One valid DV-resons is that a question does not show any research effort. Do you see any effort in the question? (How, as this question has been asked almost instantly after the mentioned comment in the other question).

Comment: @Olaf I see a question that plausibly someone wouldn't know how to research. Anyone who knows what terms to search on is likely to know the answer already.

Comment: @Olaf right but UNICODE == ASCII for codes < 128.

Comment: @MichaelWalz: The codes: yes. But not necessarily the **encoding**. This is only true for UTF-8 (and one reason I prefer this encoding), not for the wider codes (doesn't windows use some UTF-16 variant?).

Comment: @Olaf yes, but 'A' == 65 in UTF-8 **and** UTF-16 and all other ASCII derived encodings I know.

Comment: @Olaf: Windows does use UTF-16, but not for the `char` type. So far as I can tell the question is about `char`, not `wchar_t` or multi-byte encodings.

Comment: I wouldn't say that it is less portable, it just has different meaning. `char a = 65;` means you want to store the number `65` in a char data type, but you don't care what character that represents. `char a = 'A';` means you want to store the character `A`, but you don't char what the binary representation of that character is.

Comment: @SteveJessop: nor does the C library support multi-byte encodings for `char`, less variable-size characters.

Comment: @MichaelWalz: CCMIIW, but UTF-16 uses 2 octets to encode a single character. Depending on endianess, You will get a very different result when reading the first octet of a serialised UTF-16 string. And the next octet will not even yield the next character, as it does for UTF-8 with only the ASCII codepage.

Comment: @Olaf: UTF-16 uses either 2 or 4 octets for a character, it's a variable-length encoding. Fortunately though, the question isn't about what you see as the first byte of a multibyte encoding, it's about the encoding used for `char`. Which as you say isn't exactly ASCII, but is a superset of ASCII.

Comment: @SteveJessop: "Which as you say isn't exactly ASCII, but is a superset of ASCII" - I definitively did not say that! It is not correct. And I clearly wrote about serialised UTF-16, i.e. packed into `char`.

Comment: @Olaf: you said, "Actually almost no system today uses ASCII". Beyond that you were talking about something irrelevant to the question, viz. multibyte encodings. The question is about `char`, and the encoding used by Windows for `char` is a superset of ASCII.

Comment: @SteveJessop: I don't see a Windows tag!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`A` is represented by 65 in ASCII; but that doesn't mean that every character system will represent it by 65.

If you write

```
char a = 65;
```

then you're implicitly assuming that the system will be using ASCII. That's less portable than writing

```
char a = 'A';
```

which doesn't make that assumption.

Comment: that's a lovely explanation. I've upvoted before I lose the privilege ;-)

Answer (score 2):

65 is ASCII code for `A`, which can work on many systems, but what if the system does not support ASCII or doesn't have 65 for `A`? If that happens, then it's less portable due to the dependence on the system.

```
char a = 'A';
```

is a char literal which will work on all systems, but:

```
char a = 65;
```

is ASCII and may not work on all systems. You basically depend on the fact that the user is using ASCII, and depending on the user is never dependable.

Comment: Many thanks for this. I've upvoted while I still can !

Answer (score 1):

If the variable `a` should store the letter 'A', then it's better to write

```
char a = 'A';
```

because it is more portable, since there may be other character encodings than ASCII, but also because it is clearer to the reader that `a` stores the letter 'A'.

The opposite case is even more obvious: Nobody would ever write

```
int a = 'A';
```

when `a` should hold the value '65' for a calculation.